NextJS (15) with Dynamic Routes
In my NextJs 14 app I got this route and page and it works perfect
src\app\[id]\[[...slug]]\page.tsx

I can access the id and slug (i dont need the slug, it's just there for an SEO friendly url)
interface PageProps {
  params: { id: string; slug?: string[] };
}

const Page = async ({ params }: PageProps) => {
  const { id } = params;
  .....

Doing exactly the same in a NextJs15 app, it runs fine (npm run dev) but when I build

.next/types/app/[id]/[[...slug]]/page.ts:34:29 Type error: Type
'PageProps' does not satisfy the constraint
'import("C:/aaaa/web/aaa-01/.next/types/app/[id]/[[...slug]]/page").PageProps'.
Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
Type '{ id: string; slug?: string | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise': then, catch, finally,
[Symbol.toStringTag]
32 |   33 | // Check the prop type of the entry function

34 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()
|                             ^   35 |   36 | // Check the arguments and return type of the generateMetadata function   37 | if
('generateMetadata' in entry) {


I thought let me simplify and created src\app\listing\[id]\page.tsx
with the code for page
interface PageProps {
  params: { id: string };
}
 
const Page = ({ params }: PageProps) => {
  const { id } = params;

  return <div>Page for {id}</div>;
};

export default Page;

but same error (only when i build, not run..then it's fine)

The reason is because of a change in Nextjs 15, Dynamic APIs are Asynchronous
so you would have to await the params to get the slug and id


interface PageProps {
  params: Promise<{ id: string }>;
}

const Page = async ({ params }: PageProps) => {
  const { id } = await params;

  return <div>Page for {id}</div>;
};

export default Page;



